# StatusUpdate Discord Bot

Tags: java, discord-jda

This is my code to update the Status:

```
String[] status = new String[] {"Version: 1.5.0", "https://discord.gg/arWEM2h", "Love Backxtar", "You want me!", "Type: ~help", "User Counter: %members"};
    int next = 60;

    public void onSecond() {

        if(next%5 == 0) {

            if(!hasStarted) {
                hasStarted = true;
                StatChannelCommand.onStartUp();
            }

            Random rand = new Random();
            int i = rand.nextInt(status.length);

            shardMan.getShards().forEach(jda -> {
                String text = status[i].replaceAll("%members", "" + jda.getUsers().size());

                jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing(text));
            });

            StatChannelCommand.checkStats();

            if(next == 0) {
            next = 60;

            }
        }
        else {
            next--;
        }
    }
```

But the `String` is running every second. I thought it was every 5 seconds. I did 60 sec % 5. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter the method `onSecond()` for the first time, the condition `next%5 == 0` will be `true`. The variable `next` will not be updated, because this happens only in the `else` part. So, on next run of the method `next` will still be `60`.

Comment: fixxed it .. there was missing a next--; below the last next--;